# Trying to get column data from pivot table laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

Hi I'm trying to output a certain column from my pivot table. To show you what I have tried, I will first show you my models (my pivot tables are ordertasks and tagtasks):

Task table:

```
class Task extends \Eloquent {

    // Add your validation rules here
    public static $rules = [
        // 'title' => 'required'
    ];

    // Don't forget to fill this array
    protected $fillable = ['task_name','task_description','hour','difficulty'];

    public function ordertask()
    {   
        //oneToMany
        return $this->hasMany('Ordertask', 'id_task', 'id');
    }

    public function tagtask()
    {   
        //oneToMany
        return $this->hasMany('Tagtask', 'id_task', 'id');
    }


}
```

Tagtask table:

```
<?php

class Tagtask extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = ['id_tag','id_task'];

    public function task()
    {   
        //manyToOne
        return $this->belongsTo('Task', 'id_task', 'id');
        //return $this->belongsTo('Task');
    }
    public function tag()
    {   
        //manyToOne
        return $this->belongsTo('Tag', 'id_tag', 'id');

    }
}
```

Ordertask table:

```
<?php

class Ordertask extends \Eloquent {

    // Add your validation rules here
    public static $rules = [
        // 'title' => 'required'
    ];

    // Don't forget to fill this array
    protected $fillable = ['id_order','id_task', 'hour', 'hourprice','id_user', 'createdBy'];

    public function user()
    {   
        //manyToOne
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'id_user', 'id');
        //return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function task()
    {   
        //manyToOne
        return $this->belongsTo('Task', 'id_task', 'id');
        //return $this->belongsTo('Task');
    }
}
```

Here is my TaskController.php with the following piece of code:

```
public function index()
    {
        $Tasks=Task::with('tagtask','ordertask')->get(); 
        return View::make('user.tasks.index', compact('Tasks'));
    }
```

Okay now comes the part where I want to show $Task->ordertask['id_user'] on my browser with the following piece of code:

```
@if (count($Tasks)) 
<ul>
   @foreach($Tasks as $Task)
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <li>
            {{--as a third parameter we need to pass in the id of task, because it needs to be fed to
            our actual user.task.edit route. --}}
            {{link_to_route('user.tasks.edit', $Task['task_name'], array($Task->id))}}
         </li>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <li>   
            {{$Task->ordertask['id_user']}}
         </li>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <li>   
            {{$Task['task_hour']}}
         </li>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <li>
            {{Form::open(array('route'=>array('user.tasks.destroy',$Task->id),
            'method'=>'delete','class'=>'destroy'))}}
            {{Form::submit('Delete')}}
            {{Form::close()}}
         </li>
      </div>
   </div>
   @endforeach
</ul>
@endif
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work because I get the following error:

```
Undefined index: id_user
```

Instead of:

```
{{$Task->ordertask['id_user']}}
```

I have also tried this just to see what output it gave me:

```
{{$Task->ordertask}}
```

Which gave me the following output:

```
[{"id":5,"id_order":2,"id_task":1,"hour":63,"hourprice":15,"id_user":5,"createdBy":4,"created_at":"2014-10-13 10:21:33","updated_at":"2014-10-13 10:21:33"}]
```

So gladly I want to output id_user from the ordertask table. Gladly I'm waiting on your answer. Anyway thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Task can have many order tasks, so to display users instead of

```
{{$Task->ordertask['id_user']}}
```

You should use:

```
@foreach ($Task->ordertask as $ot)
 {{ $ot->id_user }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Strange it doesn't work and I did what you told me. But it doesn't go to my view because of the withPivot() method. I get the following error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::withPivot() I have also a screenshot of it: http://i.imgur.com/GtIfVB7.png    I have also checked the withPivot method, but I think it should work. But for some strange reason it doesn't. I had also run: "php artisan dump-autoload" and "composer dump-autoload". I did that just to be in case.. But unfortunately your code still didn't work..

Comment: @superkytoz Sorry, I haven't ready carefully the question, I changed my answer